# SQL query not using created index

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, indexing

I have a table with millions of data and i need to fetch the data with some conditions so I created a non clustered index , but after executing that query it still using the index scan with primary key but not the index I created.

below is the table :

```
CREATE TABLE [que].[cbsQue](
    [requestId] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    [msg] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [meta] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [actionName] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [recordId] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [branchId] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
    [kmId] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
    [queStatus] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
    [error] [nvarchar](1000) NULL,
    [response] [nvarchar](1000) NULL,
    [createdDate] [datetime2](0) NULL,
    [updatedDate] [datetime2](0) NULL,
    [customerId] [nvarchar](50) NULL)
```

Below is my query:

```
 SELECT TOP 50 Que.recordId, msg, meta, actionName
        FROM que.cbsQue Que
        WHERE (queStatus = 'TODO' OR

           (queStatus = 'FAILED' AND 
           (error LIKE 'someString1%' 
            OR error LIKE '%someString2%' 
            OR error LIKE '%someString3%' 
            OR error = 'someString4'
            OR error = 'someString5'
            OR error = 'someString6'))
            )
          ORDER BY que.createdDate DESC
```

Below is the index I created :

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [CI_queStatus] ON [que].[cbsQue]
(
    [queStatus] ASC
)
INCLUDE([error])
```

how do I use this index to be used in query ?
And is there a way to rewrite the where clause more effectively ?
And the reason for not using the above index might be due to using or in where clause ?

Comment: You pretty much cannot.  Unless `status` is really selective, then your only hope is a full text index.

Comment: A query won't use an index if it doesn't help, or if it's actually more expensive to use than not. How many records are there? How many `queStatus` values? If there are only two, the server would have to scan all values anyway and *still* have to order the results by `CreatedDate`

Comment: Searching for strings in the *middle* of a field can't be accelerated by an index anyway.

Comment: can you pls try using a subquery `...FROM (SELECT recordId, msg, meta, actionName,error FROM que.cbsQue WHERE queStatus IN ('FAILED' ,'TODO')) Que...`. This will ensure it is following index. I noticed this sometime improve perf.

Comment: you could use `with (index(indexName))` hint to force use of the index, but as you use non-sargable conditions (`LIKE '%someString3%'`) this will probably not be an improvement

Comment: let's say I remove the LIKE operator and replace with actual string, will it be then use my index ?